# How to check chicagoboss version

Tags: erlang, chicagoboss

We have more time to release our a `Chicagoboss framework` project. Since we're thinking to update it to its latest version. But I don't know what's the way to find its current version.

Since  - How can I find the version of ChicagoBoss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version number is stored in the `.app` file. In the original source code look for `boss.app.src`. On GitHub it can be viewed here: https://github.com/ChicagoBoss/ChicagoBoss/blob/v0.8.14/src/boss.app.src The relevant line is:

```
{vsn, "0.8.14"},
```

If Chicago Boss is already compiled and running you can still find the version by looking for a file named `boss.app` inside one of your `ebin/` directories somewhere in your release.